# Localhost not working and running on different network?

Tags: node.js, windows-10, create-react-app

**Overview**

- Win 10 pro, 64bit
- static-server works from localhost
- All other node.js servers stop working on localhost,127.0.0.1 and only works on 172.16.xxx.xxx host

From the source I can see that static-server host is 0.0.0.0 which is the same as mine. I run my server on 0.0.0.0 https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback

All this happened suddenly on my windows machine and on several web apps with webpack. I installed windows again and the issue persists.

I use `WebpackDevServer` with host : `0.0.0.0`

**Details**

I'm running on a brand new win 10 with some vpn installed.

So I have these 3 apps

- webpack-app on host 0.0.0.0:9080
- static-server on port 9080 (should be localhost as well)
- webpack-app with react-create-app on port 3000

I start the webpack-app on port 9080 and I go to the browser and says "This site can’t be reached,localhost refused to connect." (I'm 100% sure is running on 9080 because all my webpack apps stop working at once)

[image]

I now start static-server and runs on port 9080, doesn't complain at all! Now I go to the browser and it opens the page on port 9080.

So now I think I'm running on 2 different networks. Here is how it looks in windows:

[image]

So now I look if somebody is listening to the port 9080 and I see this:

[image]

I turn off the static-server and it disappears. Means that the static-server correctly shows up there.

Also there is no other node.exe process over there. So where did my webpack-app ended up?

Now after some times something popups there on port 3000

[image]

Not sure why there are so many on the same port, I go to that url and it works. But doesn't work from localhost:3000.

What is going on? why it doesnt work from localhost anymore?

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is **not localhost**, it's "any", meaning accept connections from any interface.

Comment: hum, so how come static-server works and my webpack server worked before on localhost?

Comment: `localhost` resolves to an address on your loopback interface, which is included in **any interface**.  Stop making multiple things listen on the same port.

Comment: I'm confused, I only have 2, 3 server now to test. Some work on localhost/127.0.0.1 some only work on the 172.xxx.xxx.xxx what is the problem?

"Stop making multiple things listen on the same port." I did that just to test. Normally it should complain that another thing is listening on the same port and is not complaining. So something is wrong there as well.

Comment: I restarted a few times my windows machine and now it works. lol

Comment: I'm having the same issue again, anybody have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Windows Subsystem for Linux, especially WSL2, keep in mind that it runs in a Hyper-V virtual machine with a virtual NIC. In other words, it creates its own virtual network.

According to the [WSL2 FAQs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-faq):

> the new architecture uses virtualized networking components. This
> means that in initial preview builds WSL 2 will behave more similarly
> to a virtual machine, e.g: WSL 2 will have a different IP address than
> the host machine. We are committed to making WSL 2 feel the same as
> WSL 1, and that includes improving our networking story.

As a result, the development server will run at a different address than 127.0.0.1 (aka localhost). This is why a connection refused error is returned when calling localhost from the browser.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#accessing-a-wsl-2-distribution-from-your-local-area-network-lan) is a possible solution, as suggested by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issues as above. Cleared my browser data and cache, it worked like a charm!!

Answer (score -1):

So very strangely after a few restarts it just works. My node.js server listens on 0.0.0.0 instead of 172.xxx.xxx.xxx. I'm really confused as why it works now and why was not working before. If somebody can figure out would be wonderful. Thanks everybody for the help.

Edit: Happened again and I fixed like this: I disabled all my docker and expressvpn apps to start on windows start and restarted my pc, now works.

Edit 2: Happened again and I fixed by closing express vpn and disabling my wifi. I only use the wired Ethernet cable. No need to restart this time.

I think something is going on with my windows machine. Not sure why there are to networks.

Comment: So the only answer was to work from a wired connection?